# Changing the image button color when date is not current in TextView

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am developing an android app which consists of two image buttons namely "previous" and "next" and the TextView which displays current date using SimpleDateFormat when application is opened.

Initially, when date is current displayed in TextBox, the previous button is of green color and next button is of red color. What I want is that, as soon as user presses previous button and yesterday's date is displayed, the next button color should change to green and as soon as he presses next button and again the current date gets displayed, the next button changes to red. i.e. next button should be red only and only if date is current otherwise it should be green.

How to do it? Please help me with the same. I am new to android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Lets suppose first button name is previousButton and second button name is nextButton in xml. Write a onClickListener and when previousButton is clicked i.e in onClick() method get the nextButton instance for eg.

```
Button nextButton = (Button)findViewById (R.id.<name of button in xml>);
```

and change the color of your need.

```
nextButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
```

Comment: This just changes my next button to green but doesn't changes the same to red when date is current in textview. please help me with the same.